# How to send extra data to api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js

Hello guys I am trying to send the shipping address to api/checkout. I tried sending the body as an object and take cart details and shipping address as object properties, but that did not work. So I am am asking is there any way to send cart details and shipping address in body?
here is route.js:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { validateCartItems } from "use-shopping-cart/utilities";
import { inventory } from "@/config/inventory";
import { stripe } from "@/lib/stripe";

export async function POST(request) {
  const cartDetails = await request.json();
  const lineItems = validateCartItems(inventory, cartDetails);
  const origin = request.headers.get("origin");
  const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
    submit_type: "pay",
    mode: "payment",
    payment_method_types: ["card"],
    line_items: lineItems,
    shipping_address_collection: {
      allowed_countries: ["US"],
    },
    shipping_options: [
      {
        shipping_rate: "shr_1Nlx6dJWKRwaU5FYLj34H9wO",
      },
    ],
    billing_address_collection: "auto",
    success_url: `${origin}/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
    cancel_url: `${origin}/cart`,
  });
  return NextResponse.json(session);
}
```

page.jsx: (its a snippet)

```
 const {
    cartDetails,
    incrementItem,
    decrementItem,
    removeItem,
    formattedTotalPrice,
    totalPrice,
    cartCount,
    redirectToCheckout,
  } = useShoppingCart();

const requestBody = {
    cartDetails: cartDetails,
    shippingAddress: {
      name: "John Doe",
      street: "123 Main St",
      city: "Example City",
    },
  };
 async function onCheckout() {
    setLoading(true);
    const response = await fetch("/api/checkout", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(cartDetails),
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    const result = await redirectToCheckout(data.id);
    if (result?.error) {
      console.error(result);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }
```

Now this code works already and takes me to stripe checkout page. I just want to send the shipping address as well. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to assemble the body as JSON on the API side, you need to set the `Content-Type` header accordingly:

```
const response = await fetch("/api/checkout", {
  method: "POST",
  body: JSON.stringify(cartDetails),
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
});
```